# how to install tcl on solaris sparc

Tags: tcl, solaris, expect, sparc

I have a solaris machine configuration: `SunOS indevel07 5.10 Generic_147440-15 sun4v sparc sun4v`. I am trying to install `expect utility` on this. expect utility requires tcl to be installed. I have tried to install that too, but i am getting errors. I have downloaded the *tcl-8.5.12-sol10-sparc-local.gz* and *expect-5.45-sol10-sparc-local.gz* from sunfreeware. I have unzipped them and tried to install them like `pkgadd -d pkgname`. I am getting errors like:

```
ERROR: attribute verification of </usr/local/man/man3/Tcl_Seek.3> failed
    pathname does not exist
```

There are lots of errors like this. I tried to troubleshoot it by googling but could not find anything about it. I am stuck with my development because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who want to install tcl please refer this URL. it has got steps to do that. URL: http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1174_Installing-Tcl-and-Expect-on-Solaris-10-a-checklist.html

Answer (score 3):

Try building Tcl/Tk and Expect from the source. Here is the instruction - [How to Compile Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/compile.html). Expect download - [Obtaining Expect for UNIX](http://expect.sourceforge.net/#unix). That worked for me on Solaris 10 and I did not hit any serious bumps.

Comment: what u r saying i had tried on linux and it worked there. but i have a solaris sparc 10 server which now needs expect utility to install. i had downloaded the sparc compatible software of tcl and expect utility form sunfreeware and tried to install it. but i got above error. what should i do in that case?

Comment: I have Sparc processor as well and Solaris 10, so my configuration is very similar to yours. I managed to build Tcl and Expect from source. I had to do it because ActiveState stopped providing free Tcl distribution for Solaris. And the someties stuff on sunfreeware is outdated. Did you try my suggestion on Solaris? If yes did you get any errors?

Comment: hey i tried ur suggestion but now the problem is my /usr directory(which is the default directory of installation) is a mounted directory with read-only file system. is there any way that i can install the tcl/expect in some other non mounted directory?

Comment: Absolutely. You need to supply installation directory to `configure` script: `./configure --prefix=/export/home/spiderman`. Run `./configure --help` to see all installation options.

Comment: thanks man. it worked. Also for those who want to install this utility please refer to this URL which has steps for how to install this on solaris machine URL: http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1174_Installing-Tcl-and-Expect-on-Solaris-10-a-checklist.html